# Netburner PINK to POST variables to Universal Devices ISY

Tags: jquery

I have a [NetBurner PINK](http://www.netburner.com/products/serial-enabled-web-server/pink70) web-server running part of my home automation system.
It uses HTML files, and .jS
It uses jQuery to update the web page's vars.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Home Automation System</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="43200"> 



</head>
<meta name=viewport content='width=700'>

<body>


 <table class="ds_box" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="ds_conclass" style="display: none;">
  <tr><td id="ds_calclass"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <script src="calendar.js"></script>
 <h1>Home Automation System</h1>
 <div id="main">
 <h4>Work Day</h4>
 <form Method = "post" action ="/index.html">
  <table border=2 cellpadding =1 align="center">
   <TR>
    <TH colspan = "2">Temperature</TH>
    <TH>Current Setting</TH>
    <TH colspan = "2">Wake <span class="subtitle">(time/temp)</span></TH>
    <TH colspan = "2">Leave <span class="subtitle">(time/temp)</span></TH>
    <TH colspan = "2">Return <span class="subtitle">(time/temp)</span></TH>
    <TH colspan = "2">Sleep <span class="subtitle">(time/temp)</span></TH>
    <Td colspan = "2"><span style="font-weight:bold">Mini-Split</span>:
    <Input id="radOn1" name="Nb_var93" type= "radio" Value=1 onClick="borderColourChange(true); ">Heat
     <Input id="radOff1" name="Nb_var93" type= "radio" Value=0 onClick="borderColourChange(false);">AC
    </Td>
   </TR>
    
   <TR>
    <TD class="leftHandTitle">Office</TD>
    <TD><input readonly name= "Nb_var01"  style="font-size: 105%;border:none;" value ="<Nb_var01>" size = 2>°F</TD>
    <TD><input name= "Nb_var02" value="<Nb_var02>" size = 2>°F</TD>
    <TD><select id="hr1" class="hr <Nb_var03>" onChange="createHour('hr1','min1','output1');"></select>:<select id="min1" class="min <Nb_var03>" onChange="createHour('hr1','min1','output1');"></select>
     <input id="output1" type="hidden" name="Nb_var03"/></TD>
    <TD><input name= "Nb_var04" value="<Nb_var04>" size = 2>°F</TD>
    <TD><select id="hr2" class="hr <Nb_var05>" onChange="createHour('hr2','min2','output2');"></select>:<select id="min2" class="min <Nb_var05>" onChange="createHour('hr2','min2','output2');"></select>
     <input id="output2" type="hidden" name="Nb_var05"/></TD>
    <TD><input name= "Nb_var06" value="<Nb_var06>" size = 2>°F</TD>
    <TD><select id="hr3" class="hr <Nb_var07>" onChange="createHour('hr3','min3','output3');"></select>:<select id="min3" class="min <Nb_var07>" onChange="createHour('hr3','min3','output3');"></select>
     <input id="output3" type="hidden" name="Nb_var07"/></TD>
    <TD><input name= "Nb_var08" value="<Nb_var08>" size = 2>°F</TD>
    <TD><select id="hr4" class="hr <Nb_var09>" onChange="createHour('hr4','min4','output4');"></select>:<select id="min4" class="min <Nb_var09>" onChange="createHour('hr4','min4','output4');"></select>
     <input id="output4" type="hidden" name="Nb_var09"/></TD>
    <TD><input name= "Nb_var10" value="<Nb_var10>" size = 2>°F</TD>
    <TD><Input id="radOn2" name="Nb_var86" type= "radio" Value=1 onClick="this.form.submit();">ON</TD>
    <TD><Input id="radOff2" name="Nb_var86" type= "radio" Value=0 onClick="this.form.submit();">OFF</TD>
   </TR>
```

Currently, through my ISY I can send ISY vars to PINK and now
I am trying to send NB vars to my [Universal devices ISY](https://www.universal-devices.com/residential/isy994i-series/).

My question is how to have the NB POST and constantly update to various vars in the ISY?
I can  affect it by entering this in the browser:

```html
http://isy_ip/rest/vars/set/<var-type>/<var-id>/<value>
```

ISY responds:

```html
<RestResponse succeeded="true">
  <status>200</status>
</RestResponse>
```

What code is necessary to put in the PINK to make that happen?
Please go easy on me, I'm real new at this.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the Netburner PINK supports udp protocol and so does the ISY.
I need to set up a udp connection between the 2.